# What lifestyle expenses are associated with the Yawning Portal?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms, world-building, city-design

The party has just begun *Dungeon of the Mad Mage*.  After their first trip down the well, they have sensibly taken Durnan up on his offer of rooms in the Yawning Portal where they can stay in between expeditions.

In deciding how much to charge them, I am wondering what "Lifestyle Expenses" the Yawning Portal would be considered, and leaning towards "Comfortable" if they share a room or "Wealthy" if they get private rooms and additional services, but "Aristocratic" would not be available, nor "Modest" and below (unless they somehow took a position as waitstaff and stayed in servant's quarters).

I have looked through *Dungeon of the Mad Mage* (which I have on roll20, making it difficult to search), as well as pages 6 and 7 of *Tales of the Yawning Portal*, but I am not finding anything about **costs or services associated with the Inn**.

I am wondering if there is any canon source for such things.
5e is preferred, but any edition is acceptable.

Answer (score 12):

You're probably pretty close to on the money.  But they probably don't need to share rooms to be "comfortable".

According to *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*:

> The upper floors of the Yawning Portal contain comfortable, nicely appointed rooms for guests.
>
> Durnan, the proprietor, charges standard prices for food, drink, and lodging (see chapter 5 of the Player’s Handbook for costs).

According to Chapter 5 of *The Player's Handbook*, a "Comfortable" lifestyle, described in part as "a private room in a fine inn", is 2 gp per day, to include lodging, food, clothing, and equipment maintenance.

Therefore, just going on what the two books say, the Yawning Portal offers comfortable rooms, and a comfortable lifestyle is 2 gp per day.

If they want to go wealthy, that would get a single character a suite of rooms.  It's not clear if the Yawning Portal offers suites.